# Soap Custom XMl in Ruby with Savon

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I need the request body to look as such:

```
<env:Body>

<abc:request token="0" id="1" version="4">
<category domain_id="630643"/>
</abc>

</env:Body>
```

How do I add the additional attributes to ?

Additionally, how do you change the encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-16? Not able to find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### SOAP body with custom attributes:

```
client.request :abc, :request, :token => 0, :id => 1, :version => 4 do
  soap.body = {
    :category => "",
    :attributes! => { :category  => { "domain_id" => 630643 } }
  }
end
```

`Savon::Client#request` accepts a namespace, the name of the SOAP action to call as well as an optional Hash of attributes for the SOAP input tag.

```
<abc:request version="4" id="1" token="0">
```

Attributes for SOAP body tags can be set via a special `:attributes!` Hash. Notice that the `domain_id` attribute is a String, because Hash key Symbols are (by default) converted to lowerCamelCase.

```
<category domain_id="630643"></category>
```

Also notice, that [Gyoku](https://rubygems.org/gems/gyoku) did not create a self-closing tag. Savon uses Gyoku to translate Ruby Hashes to XML and the library is able to create self-closing tags, but it seems to swallow custom attributes for those (v0.4.2). [This is a bug](https://github.com/rubiii/gyoku/issues/4) and should be fixed with the next release.

[Further information and examples](http://savonrb.com) can be found in the new documentation.

#### Changing the default encoding

Savon uses [HTTPI](https://rubygems.org/gems/httpi) to execute HTTP requests and you can access the `HTTPI::Request` object via `Savon::Client#http`. Changing the default encoding to UTF-16 should be possible by setting a custom "Content-Type" header.

```
client.http.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml;charset=UTF-16"
```

Please note, that this doesn't change the encoding attribute of the xml processing instruction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Take a look at "[Send UTF-16 encoded SOAP request with Ruby and Savon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840498/send-utf-16-encoded-soap-request-with-ruby-and-savon/7847640#7847640)" for information about how to change the processing instruction.

Comment: So how is it that you can set UTF-16 encodings with soap.body?

Comment: @rubii - Any update on how to get this working? I'm using Savon 0.9.7 with client.http.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml;charset=UTF-16" and still getting an error:


       < f a u l t c o d e > s o a p : C l i e n t < / f a u l t c o d e >
       < f a u l t s t r i n g > F a i l e d   t o   p r o c e s s   S O A P   r e q u e s t .   S O A P   b o d y   n o t   i n   U T F - 1 6 .
 < / f a u l t s t r i n g >

Comment: @spectro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840498/send-utf-16-encoded-soap-request-with-ruby-and-savon/7847640#7847640