# Send UTF-16 encoded SOAP request with Ruby and Savon

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, utf-16, savon

**How do I encode the request in UTF-16? Here's what I have:**

```
  # Create Savon client
  @client = Savon::Client.new do
    wsdl.document = File.expand_path("account_list.wsdl", __FILE__)
  end

  # Set header encoding
  @client.http.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml;charset=UTF-16"

  # Setup ssl configuration
  @client.http.auth.ssl.cert_key_file = "cert_key_file.pem"
  @client.http.auth.ssl.cert_file = "cert_file.pem"
  @client.http.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file = "ca_cert_file.pem"
  @client.http.auth.ssl.verify_mode=:none

  # Execute request
  response = @client.request :account_list do
    soap.body = {
      :id => "18615618"
      }
  end
```

**Here's the begging of what's sent, notice the encoding="UTF-8":**

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-16, SOAPAction: "accountList", Content-Length: 888 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
```

**Here's the error I get:**

```
< s o a p : E n v e l o p e   x m l n s : s o a p = " h t t p : / / s c h e m a s . x m l s o a p . o r g / s o a p / e n v e l o p e / "   x m l n s : w s>d
 < s o a p : B o d y >
   < s o a p : F a u l t >
     < f a u l t c o d e > s o a p : C l i e n t < / f a u l t c o d e >
     < f a u l t s t r i n g > F a i l e d   t o   p r o c e s s   S O A P   r e q u e s t .   S O A P   b o d y   n o t   i n   U T F - 1 6 .
< / f a u l t s t r i n g >
     < d e t a i l >
       < w s d l _ o p s : e r r o r > F a i l e d   t o   p r o c e s s   S O A P   r e q u e s t .   S O A P   b o d y   n o t   i n   U T F - 1 6 .
< / w s d l _ o p s : e r r o r >
     < / d e t a i l >
   < / s o a p : F a u l t >
 < / s o a p : B o d y >
< / s o a p : E n v e l o p e >
```

Answer (score 1):

Savon currently only supports [changing the XML directive tag](https://github.com/rubiii/savon/blob/v0.9.7/spec/savon/soap/xml_spec.rb#L146) via the integrated Builder-method:

```
response = @client.request(:account_list) do
  soap.xml(:xml, :encoding => "UTF-16") { |xml| xml.id("18615618") }
end
```

You'll miss out a lot of XML-support by using this approach though. No SOAP envelope, no header or body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><id>18615618</id>
```

I'll use [your ticket](https://github.com/rubiii/savon/issues/234) to come up with a better solution asap!

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to the update! Great SOAP client BTW.

Comment: I had to compose my own XMLs with savon every time, since they were using namespaces. Savon provided me just those two (or three) xml tags, so it's not that hard to add these to those already hand-crafted. Patch for the issue above is released, so this answer should be accepted. Riight? :)